# Locking of tables in MySQL seems that they aren't able to handle the parallel request?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, rowlocking, table-locking

I locked the table using FOR UPDATE with an IF validation. However, it seems that they aren't able to handle the parallel request?

I have two samples of stored procedures. I tested these using cURL to make a parallel requests.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SAMPLE;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE(_quantity INT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE _total INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT COALESCE(SUM(price),0) + _quantity INTO _total FROM account FOR UPDATE;
   IF(_total <= 50) THEN
       CALL SAMPLE2(_quantity);
   ELSE
       SELECT 'EXCEEDED';
   END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE SAMPLE2;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE2(_quantity INT)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO account(price) VALUES(_quantity);
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

I expect the output to not exceed 50 based on my validation.

LOG OUTPUT:

```
CALL SAMPLE(?) [ [ RowDataPacket { _total: 20, _quantity: 20, 'now()': 2019-07-22T08:33:27.000Z } ],

CALL SAMPLE(?) [ [ RowDataPacket { _total: 20, _quantity: 20, 'now()': 2019-07-22T08:33:27.000Z } ],

CALL SAMPLE(?) [ [ RowDataPacket { _total: 40, _quantity: 20, 'now()': 2019-07-22T08:33:27.000Z } ],

CALL SAMPLE(?) [ [ RowDataPacket { _total: 80, _quantity: 20, 'now()': 2019-07-22T08:33:28.000Z } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { EXCEEDED: 'EXCEEDED' } ],

CALL SAMPLE(?) [ [ RowDataPacket { _total: 80, _quantity: 20, 'now()': 2019-07-22T08:33:28.000Z } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { EXCEEDED: 'EXCEEDED' } ],

CALL SAMPLE(?) [ [ RowDataPacket { _total: 80, _quantity: 20, 'now()': 2019-07-22T08:33:28.000Z } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { EXCEEDED: 'EXCEEDED' } ],
```

On the second call, it seems that they didn't read the inserted value.

Data Inserted.

```
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | price | created             |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |    20 | 2019-07-25 13:44:51 |
|  2 |    20 | 2019-07-25 13:44:51 |
|  3 |    20 | 2019-07-25 13:44:51 |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

What I need is the summation of price <= 50. But the above output showed 60.

Comment: What you are testing by adding `for update`?

Comment: I am trying to lock the table to prevent the parallel request from exceeding my validation

Comment: Can you explain in detail like what you need as a result

Comment: I edited my question above. Please check.

Comment: I couldn't understand the LOG OUTPUT but i guess data inserted should stop with `id`=2?

Comment: Yes that is right. The LOG OUTPUT is the **Parameter passed (which is quantity)  + summation of price**, **Parameter passed**, **Date function**

Comment: So is it like application output? like php if so add the tag

Comment: I think the issue raises due to nested call try the insert directly in the same sp sample

Comment: If my theory is wrong, just add the expected LOG OUTPUT

Comment: I am having a hard time replicating this issue. Sometimes it exceeds, sometimes it does not.  I tried inserting it directly in the same SP. But still,  summation of 60 occurs.

Comment: Or try adding explicit `start transaction` and `commit` and inserting in single SP.

Comment: check your Isolation level Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Comment: I cannot replicate it by adding `start transaction ` and `commit`. But I am not sure if this explicit `start transaction` should fix it. I have a similar behavior in production with explicit `transaction` and they bypassed my validation.

Comment: Can you recommend other libraries/tools for making parallel request? I believe looping is concurrent, not parallel.

Comment: Since the docs said that to hold a lock you should use between the transaction explicitly. Use can read the note: on the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html